# Regular Expression : How to capture the optional group

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

I want to capture number of groups from this string -

```
%May 11 10:03:49:448 2000 AB-CDE SHELL/6/SHELL_CMD: -Task=vt0-IPAddr=172.0.0.0-User=manager; Command is display info
%May 11 10:03:51:122 2000 AB-CD-E SSH/6/SSH_LOGOUT: STEL user manager (IP: 172.0.0.0) logged out.
```

The regex I wrote is as follows -

```
^%(\w{3})\s+(\d+)\s*([0-9]+\s?:\s?[0-9]+\s?:\s?[0-9]+):[0-9]+\s*(\d{4})?\s*\S*\s*(.*)/(\d+)/\S*:(.*);(.*)
```

This caputures the following groups from first line -

```
1. Group: May
2. Group: 11
3. Group: 10:03:49
4. Group: 2000
5. Group: SHELL
6. Group: 6
7. Group: -Task=vt0-IPAddr=172.0.0.0-User=manager
8. Group: Command is display info
```

This does not select second line as that does not have ; in the last section.

I tried making the group 7 optional

```
^%(\w{3})\s+(\d+)\s*([0-9]+\s?:\s?[0-9]+\s?:\s?[0-9]+):[0-9]+\s*(\d{4})?\s*\S*\s*(.*)/(\d+)/\S*:(.*);?(.*)
```

Output:

```
1.1 Group: May
1.2. Group: 11
1.3. Group: 10:03:49
1.4. Group: 2000
1.5. Group: SHELL
1.6. Group: 6
1.7. Group: -Task=vt0-IPAddr=172.0.0.0-User=manager; Command is display info
1.8. Group:

2.1. Group: May
2.2. Group: 11
2.3. Group: 10:03:51
2.4. Group: 2000
2.5. Group: SSH
2.6. Group: 6
2.7. Group: STEL user manager (IP: 172.0.0.0) logged out.
2.8. Group:
```

but still it does not meet my requirements.
Why 1.7 line doesnot spilt even it has ;
and I want 2.7 output to come in 2.8 and 2.7 should come as empty as second line does not have ;

Is there any way we can achieve this using regex?

Comment: I am facing another small issue with the regex -
%Jun 13 01:10:00:942 2016 HP OPTMOD/4/MODULE_IN: -Slot=3;GigabitEthernet3/0/0: The transceiver is 1000_BASE_SX_SFP.

For this line, the 5th capture group is coming as 

`OPTMOD/4/MODULE_IN: -Slot=3;GigabitEthernet3:`
But I want it to be OPTMOD only.
I guess it is due to we have multiple : in the line. But could not figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-capturing optional group (`(?:)`):

```
^%(\w{3})\s+(\d+)\s*([0-9]+\s?:\s?[0-9]+\s?:\s?[0-9]+):[0-9]+\s*(\d{4})?\s*\S*\s*(.*)/(\d+)/\S*:(?:(.*);)?(.*)
```

This will make the group 7 optional.

Usage: https://regex101.com/r/oS3bN6/1